# How do I print error message on this particular ping command?

Tags: linux, termux

```
ping 8.8.8.8 | while read pong; do echo "$(date +%F_%T) - - $pong"; done >> file.txt
```

When the internet drops it shows "Destination Unreachable" only in the terminal(termux android) not in the text file. I want the error message also in the text file.

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&>` to redirect both stdout & stderr to output file.

For example:

```
$ ping <IPaddr> | while read pong; do echo "$(date +%F_%T) - - $pong"; done >> file.txt 2>&1

[root@localhost tmp]#  ping 192.168.56.149 | while read pong; do echo "$(date +%F_%T) - - $pong"; done > file.txt 2>&1
^C
[root@localhost tmp]# cat file.txt
2018-09-18_18:03:28 - - PING 192.168.56.149 (192.168.56.149) 56(84) bytes of data.
2018-09-18_18:03:28 - - From 192.168.56.102 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
2018-09-18_18:03:28 - - From 192.168.56.102 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
2018-09-18_18:03:28 - - From 192.168.56.102 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
[root@localhost tmp]#
```

Comment: The results are the same. Still not showing error message in the text file.

Comment: I'm not saying about an error message of destination host, What I'm trying to describe is an error message when the internet stops working.

Comment: @DominickTorres check my updated answer, it should work.

Comment: Still same results. I uploaded an image so you can see the results. I restarted the internet between time 09:48:24 ~ 09:50:28 and didn't get destination unreachable between this time, only in the terminal emulator(termux).

Comment: @DominickTorres, its working fine for me. Are you sure you are using above command exactly ?

Comment: Actually it works for my like that

"$ ping <IPaddr>2>&1 | while read pong; do echo "$(date +%F_%T) - - $pong"; done >> file.txt ",


The "2>&1" comes after the IP Address, someone answered me in another topic. Thanks tho!